# How to call openorcreateDatabase method in onReceive method in android?

Tags: android

```
public class SmsSenderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
SQLiteDatabase server;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // ---get the SMS message passed in---
    SQLiteDatabase server= openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDatabase",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);;
    }

}
```

The error is:

> The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for
>   the type SmsSenderReceiver

Answer (score 1):

`openOrCreateDatabase()` is a `Context` method. A `BroadcastReceiver` is not a `Context`, but `onReceive()` receives one as an argument. Therefore:

```
SQLiteDatabase server = context.openOrCreateDatabase(...);
```

Consider using a `SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage your databases though.